# Storing key_str and init_vetor in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aes, password-encryption

I have an application in which I need to store Active Directory service account credentials. In my development system it's stored plain text to ensure that everything connects correctly but now I'm investigating how to secure everything down before I start to show this to the testing team etc.

I've gone through the simple process of following the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) on using MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT and opted to use the AES-256-CBC encryption mode.

Is it accepted practice that in order to use AES_DECRYPT to retrieve the password, both `key_str` and `init_vector` need to be stored within their respective fields in the table?

Comment: If you think about it !!!! It would rather destroy the point of encryption if you stored the keys used to encrypt a data in the table with the encrypted data. That would allow anyone that get hold of yruo odatabase to decrypt with complete ease

Comment: If its just a password then a HASH should be enough

Comment: A hash wouldn't work because it's a service account, therefore no-one is providing a password for it to be compared to (I store user accounts passwords that way, using native PHP comparison techniques).  As for the `key_str` or `init_vector`, it kinda defeats the object doesn't it? 

So, what's the solution? At least one of these two should be stored in the application and perhaps encrypted through an alternative method?